# dividing all columns in pyspark SQL

Tags: sql, pyspark, divide

I am new to Spark and this might be a straightforward problem.

I have a table in pyspark DF1, with a column name "A" and some other columns. The other column names might change in various cases. I want to generate a table DF2 by dividing the values of these "other" columns over A. The columns of DF2 would also be the "other" columns.

For example for

```
DF1 = sql_sc.createDataFrame([(1, 2,3), (2, 4,6), (3, 6,9), (4, 8,12), (5, 10,15)], ["A", "B","C"])
```

The result would be a table as:

```
 DF2 = sql_sc.createDataFrame([(2,3), (2,3), (2,3), (2,3), (2,3)], ["B","C"]
```

How can I do this task in pyspark SQL ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use DataFrame.columns to iterate over the columns and then just use the divide operator to perform your row-wise math. Like this:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import col

DF1 = spark.createDataFrame([(1, 2,3), (2, 4,6), (3, 6,9), (4, 8,12), (5, 10,15)], ["A", "B","C"])  
DF1.show()

df = DF1
for field in DF1.columns:
    if field != 'A':
        df = df.withColumn(field, col(field) / col("A"))

DF2 = df.drop('A')
DF2.show()
```

Which outputs this:

```
+---+---+---+
|  A|  B|  C|
+---+---+---+
|  1|  2|  3|
|  2|  4|  6|
|  3|  6|  9|
|  4|  8| 12|
|  5| 10| 15|
+---+---+---+

+---+---+
|  B|  C|
+---+---+
|2.0|3.0|
|2.0|3.0|
|2.0|3.0|
|2.0|3.0|
|2.0|3.0|
+---+---+
```